# How to know if "fputcsv" has been successfully executed

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I have been using a php script to export some data from a table using MySQL query then want to delete those data from the table. The below script exports the data to CVS file. So far it is working fine but I want to add a condition to know that if all the data has been successfully saved to CSV file, then run a php script to delete those data from the table.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row) or die('can not create file 2');
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: it Returns the length of the written string or FALSE on failure.

Comment: Can you state how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(!fputcsv($fp, $row))
        die('can not create file 2');
}
```

Here you go, but it would be better to check before trying to write

```
if(fopen("yourfile.csv", "w+")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if(!fputcsv($fp, $row))
            die('Something happened during the write of the line '. $row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I use "fputcsv($fp, $row) ;" above if statement or rewrite the whole process like you mentioned here?

Comment: It should be noted that the docs state that the return value of fputcsv is the amount of bytes written, so receiving a truthy value will not always mean the call was a complete success. In order to know it was a success, you will need to know the amount of bytes expected to be written, and compare it to the result of fputcsv.